# System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have this code which gets soap envelope(varchar(max)) from DB and create a XmlDictionaryReader from that and the goal is to create Message(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message).

This is the code

```
public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{           
    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));               
    return stream;          
}

public static XmlDictionaryReader GenerateXmlDictionaryReader(string s, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quota)
{           
    using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(s))
    {
        return XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, quota);
    }           
}
```

and I am calling the above methods here

```
var reader = GenerateXmlDictionaryReader(soapenv, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);                       
message = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
```

and I am getting this error

```
System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading.
   at System.IO.__Error.ReadNotSupported()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.TryEnsureBytes(Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.BufferElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.ReadStartElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedMessage..ctor(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, MessageVersion desiredVersion)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(XmlDictionaryReader envelopeReader, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, MessageVersion version)
```

and I have also verified the soapenv is not empty and is valid xml in the code. I have no clue how to resolve this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(s))
{
    return XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, quota);
}
```

This `using` disposes (/closes) the stream as you exit the method in the `return` - your reader is sat atop a dead stream; that is why it isn't working. See L98 and L120 [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs#L120). Remove the `using`.